# Error on line 63, that I cannot seem to debug.

Tags: vbscript

This is line 63 for me: Set ipAddrFile = fso.OpenTextFile(fileName,Read,ASCII)
I was also getting an error for line 51, but adding the quotes solved my problem.. Well, It got rid of the error. I tried to do the same thing with line 63, but I get the error no matter what. I am also running this program on windows 10 and on a Windows Vista virtual computer.

And this is the Script I'm trying to debug:

```
' VBScript: IP_FileWrite.vbs
' Written by: Kathleen Williams
' Date: 2/7/18
' Class: COMP230
' Professor: Professor James Lewis
' ===================================
' This initializes a 2-dimension array
' of IP Address. The first index +100
' is the room# and the second index+1
' is the computer# in the room.
dim ipAddress(5,3)
  ipAddress(0,0)="192.168.10.11"
  ipAddress(0,1)="192.168.10.12"
  ipAddress(0,2)="192.168.10.13"
  ipAddress(0,3)="192.168.10.14"
  ipAddress(1,0)="192.168.10.19"
  ipAddress(1,1)="192.168.10.20"
  ipAddress(1,2)="192.168.10.21"
  ipAddress(1,3)="192.168.10.22"
  ipAddress(2,0)="192.168.10.27"
  ipAddress(2,1)="192.168.10.28"
  ipAddress(2,2)="192.168.10.29"
  ipAddress(2,3)="192.168.10.30"
  ipAddress(3,0)="192.168.10.35"
  ipAddress(3,1)="192.168.10.36"
  ipAddress(3,2)="192.168.10.37"
  ipAddress(3,3)="192.168.10.38"
  ipAddress(4,0)="192.168.10.43"
  ipAddress(4,1)="192.168.10.44"
  ipAddress(4,2)="192.168.10.45"
  ipAddress(4,3)="192.168.10.46"
  ipAddress(5,0)="192.168.10.51"
  ipAddress(5,1)="192.168.10.52"
  ipAddress(5,2)="192.168.10.53"
  ipAddress(5,3)="192.168.10.54" 

' Define constants, variables and set object properties
CONST ForReading = 1
CONST ForWriting = 2
CONST ForAppending = 8 
Const ASCII = 0
'Defining the Variables
fileName = "C:\VBScripts\IP_Addresses.csv"
ipAddrStr = ""

' Create New Folder
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If fso.FileExists(fileName) Then
    fso.DeleteFile(fileName)
End If
Set ipAddrFile = fso.CreateTextFile("fileName,ForWriting,ASCII")

' Read from array and write a line of text.
For room = 0 to 5
  For computer = 0 to 3
    ipAddrStr = CStr(room+100) & "," & CStr(computer+1) & "," & _
     ipAddress(room,computer) & vbCrLf
    ipAddrFile.Write(ipAddrStr)
  Next
Next
ipAddrFile.close
' Set object properties and close file object.
Set ipAddrFile = fso.OpenTextFile(fileName,Read,ASCII)
WScript.Echo iPAddrFile.ReadAll
ipAddrFile.close
```

Answer (score 1):

VBScript was designed by at least two people. A genius, who defined the properly named functions [CreateTextFile()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5t9b5c0c(v=vs.84).aspx) and [OpenTextFile()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/314cz14s(v=vs.84).aspx) and
their default arguments to make standard tasks - create an ASCII file, read from an ASCII file - easy:

```
Option Explicit

Const csFSpec = "48798232.txt"

Dim oFS : Set oFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim sD  : sD      = "could be an array, but is just a string for show: " & Now() 
' using *Create*TextFile + defaults to always create an ASCII File
Dim tsW : Set tsW = oFS.CreateTextFile(csFSPEC)
tsW.WriteLine sD
tsW.Close
' using OpenTextile + defaults to read from an ASCII File
' no need for a variable or .Close
WScript.Echo oFS.OpenTextFile(csFSPEC).ReadAll()
```

output:

```
cscript 48798232.vbs
could be an array, but is just a string for show: 15.02.2018 04:45:06
```

Then there came the idiot in residence and messed up `OpenTextFile()` with lots of optional parameters in arbitrary order to make it useable for file creation. From then on people mixed up those functions and their parameter lists.

```
Code 1: Set ipAddrFile = fso.CreateTextFile("fileName,ForWriting,ASCII")
Create: object.CreateTextFile(filename[, overwrite[, unicode]])
Open: object.OpenTextFile(filename[, iomode[, create[, format]]])
Code 2: Set ipAddrFile = fso.OpenTextFile(fileName,Read,ASCII)
```

Never being sure of the arguments, their data types, or their order, they use desperate means like quoting the (wrong) argument list.

So: Check the docs carefully (e.g. be aware of the difference between a boolean ForWriting vs. a numerical iomode of the same name (<-- the idiot at work, obviously) and use the defaults for simple/standard tasks.